# Insert new record with composite primary key, which consists of two foreign keys from different tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, sqlcommand

Please help me figure out how to Insert new record with composite primary key, which consists of two foreign keys from different tables.
I am working in C#, WPF if that matters.

I have three tables: Sales, SaleItem, Item.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales] (
    [saleID]     INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [saleTime]   DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [customerID] INT      NULL,
    [TIN]        INT      NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Sales] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([saleID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Sales_Customers] FOREIGN KEY ([customerID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customers] ([customerID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Sales_Company] FOREIGN KEY ([TIN]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Company] ([TIN])
);



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item] (
    [ItemSKU]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [itemName]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [volume]      FLOAT (53)    NOT NULL,
    [measureUnit] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [producer]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [supplierID]  INT           NOT NULL,
    [retailPrice] NUMERIC (18)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Item] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ItemSKU] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Item_Suppliers] FOREIGN KEY ([supplierID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Suppliers] ([supplierID])
);

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SaleItem] (
        [saleID]   INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [itemSKU]  INT NOT NULL,
        [quantity] INT NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_SaleItem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([saleID] ASC, [itemSKU] ASC),
        CONSTRAINT [FK_SaleItem_Sales] FOREIGN KEY ([saleID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Sales] ([saleID]),
        CONSTRAINT [FK_SaleItem_Item] FOREIGN KEY ([itemSKU]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Item] ([ItemSKU])
    );
```

I want to insert a new record into SaleItem table (the third one) where saleID is the last ID recorded in Sales table and ItemSKU which is equal to the value I get from another window.

I want these values:

```
SaleID = SELECT TOP 1 saleID FROM Sales ORDER BY saleID DESC";
ItemSKU = "SELECT itemName FROM Item WHERE ItemSKU = @sku";
```

I think I must do it in one query but I have no idea how. 
Can you please give me a hint? I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to remove the IDENTITY property from the dbo.SaleItem table. The IDENTITY property is only required on the parent table, dbo.Sales.

You can do a single INSERT statement like this. It uses two subqueries, which are the SELECT statements in parentheses, to get values from the other two tables.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SaleItem (saleID, itemSKU, quantity)
    VALUES ((SELECT MAX(saleID) FROM dbo.Sales),
        (SELECT ItemSKU FROM dbo.Item WHERE itemName = N'Widget'),
        50);
```

You might want to turn it into a stored procedure, like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.up_InsertSaleItem
(
    @itemName nvarchar(50),
    @quantity int
)
AS
INSERT INTO dbo.SaleItem (saleID, itemSKU, quantity)
    VALUES ((SELECT MAX(saleID) FROM dbo.Sales),
        (SELECT ItemSKU FROM dbo.Item WHERE itemName = @itemName),
        @quantity);
```

Then to use the stored procedure:

```
-- Test the stored procedure
EXEC dbo.up_InsertSaleItem @itemName=N'Widget', @quantity=50;

SELECT *
    FROM dbo.SaleItem;
```

[image]

To read more about subqueries, see Microsoft SQL Server 2012 T-SQL Fundamentals by Itzik Ben-Gan, Chapter 4: Subqueries.